# Get information from UI with BackgroundWorker and then update UI

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am filling a `DataGridView` by running a SQL query with `BackgroundWorker`. My code works perfectly if I run it directly in a button event handler, but when I put in a `DoWork` BackgroundWorker it doesn't update the UI. My code is below.

```
DataTable tab1table = new DataTable();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Instantiatesearch1Thread();
}

private void Instantiatesearch1Thread()
{
    search1Thread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    search1Thread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
    search1Thread.ProgressChanged += search1Thread_ProgressChanged;
    search1Thread.DoWork += search1Thread_Dowrk;
    search1Thread.RunWorkerCompleted += search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

    private void sbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    search1Thread.RunWorkerAsync();
}
void search1Thread_Dowrk(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int percentprogress = 0;
    percentprogress++;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    // Search1 button event handler
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
    {

        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(comboBox1SQL, conn))
        {
            if (comboBox1.Text.Contains("ID"))
            {
                long para = long.Parse(search1.Text);
                cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@combo1Par",
                    Value = para,
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt
                });
            }

            else if (comboBox1.Text.Contains("Other Thing") || comboBox1.Text.Contains("Other Stuff"))
            {
                string para = search1.Text;
                cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@combo1Par",
                    Value = "%" + para + "%",
                    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                });
            }
            // Clear datatable if it contains any information and then fill it
            // tab1datatable is a DataGridView
            if (tab1table != null)
                tab1table.Clear();
            cmd.Fill(tab1table);
            //tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;

        // A bunch of expensive calculations 
        }
    }
}

void search1Thread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    search1Progress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

void search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;
    tab1datatable.Refresh();
    MessageBox.Show("All Done!");
}
```

By using a `MessageBox` I discovered that the code is not accessing the `if comboBox1.Text.Contains()` statements, which I think makes sense, because that information comes from the UI and `BackgroundWorker` can't directly access the UI. This would also explain why then `tab1datatable` and `tab1table` go untouched.

I think I need to use the `Invoke` method somewhere, but I am not sure how. I took a look at [c# - Pass information to BackgroundWorker From UI during execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502451/c-sharp-pass-information-to-backgroundworker-from-ui-during-execution) but it doesn't really answer my question. If `Invoke` is what I need, how do I implement in this code to allow it to grab information from the UI and subsequently update it with the filled `DataGridView`?

Comment: Why did you commend out datasource?  You need to set datasource to null and then back to table to get the paint method to update control : cmd.Fill(tab1table);
            tab1datatable.DataSource = null; tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;

Comment: Because I updated it in the `search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted` function, instead.

Comment: Update `DataGridView` in UI thread. `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => // Insert data into grid));`

Comment: @fhnaseer it won't even access the if statements in the background thread, so I can't get to the data to fill the `DataGridView`. Would I put that into `search1Thread_Dowrk`?

Comment: Then set to null in search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: Do this. `ComboBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` And hopefully you will be able to access it from the `BackgroundThread`.

Comment: @fhnaseer - Nooooooo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do:

```
    private string search1_Text = "";
    private string comboBox1_Text = "";
    private void Instantiatesearch1Thread()
    {
        search1_Text = search1.Text;
        comboBox1_Text = comboBox1.Text;
        search1Thread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        search1Thread.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        search1Thread.ProgressChanged += search1Thread_ProgressChanged;
        search1Thread.DoWork += search1Thread_Dowrk;
        search1Thread.RunWorkerCompleted += search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted;
    }
```

You basically take a copy of the data that you need **before** you run the background worker.

Then you just access the fields in your `DoWork` code:

```
    void search1Thread_Dowrk(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int percentprogress = 0;
        percentprogress++;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        // Search1 button event handler
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlDataAdapter cmd = new SqlDataAdapter(comboBox1SQL, conn))
            {
                if (comboBox1_Text.Contains("ID"))
                {
                    long para = long.Parse(search1_Text);
                    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@combo1Par",
                        Value = para,
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.BigInt
                    });
                }

                else if (comboBox1_Text.Contains("Other Thing") || comboBox1_Text.Contains("Other Stuff"))
                {
                    string para = search1_Text;
                    cmd.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@combo1Par",
                        Value = "%" + para + "%",
                        SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar,
                    });
                }
                // Clear datatable if it contains any information and then fill it
                // tab1datatable is a DataGridView
                if (tab1table != null)
                    tab1table.Clear();
                cmd.Fill(tab1table);
                //tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;

                // A bunch of expensive calculations 
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this is a good solution or not but this works. Set `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls` to false when you initialize the `BackgroundWorker`.

```
private void Instantiatesearch1Thread()
{
    // Initialize other stuff
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
}
```

And set it to false once task is completed.

```
private void search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do your work,
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;
}
```

Comment: No idea. I am not a winform person. I do WPF with MVVM. And in MVVM background thread can easily access UI properties. Have a look at this question. There are some details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the?rq=1

Comment: @DrakeMurdoch  **Definitely  avoid this**. You just need to set the DataSource to null, then reset it with the new DataTable. Or use a BindingSource, which will do this for you. **In the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler.**

Comment: @Jimi if I do `tab1datatable.DataSource = null;
   tab1datatable.DataSource = tab1table;
   tab1datatable.Update();` in `search1Thread_RunWorkerCompleted` I get an empty table.

Comment: Find out what happens to your DataTable in the meanwhile, then. Your code never calls `ReportProgress`, thus you have somthing that you're not showing here. Do not try to hack the background Thread, you'll have more problems that you bargained for.